# How to make an object stay inside another object?

Tags: parent

I have a jewelry box,  inside the 24 different drawers I want objects to stay  put with their  textures. 
I am having     great difficulty in  achieving this..... Joining the object to the  drawer doesn't work..

It is not as simple  as copy & paste object to drawer location..

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! What do you mean by "objects staying put with their textures"? As of now your question is hard to understand. Could you maybe add some images to illustrate what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for *Parenting objects*.
Set your drawer as a parent to the jewels, and they'll move with it.

**How to**
Select the jewels, *then* select the drawer an set it as a parent.
*Object > Parent > Object*
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> *> Object*

*Objects with and without parenting.*

[image]

Further reading:
[Parenting objects in Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/relations/parents.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the outliner and shift drop the diamonds onto the box to parent them as well.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html

Comment: You're right! Forgot to mention that. Have a +1 :)